# .Net 5: Unable to start Ocelot, unsupported authentication provider

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-5, api-gateway, ocelot

I wanna implement `JWT` authentication in the Ocelot API gateway, I followed ocelot [documentation](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/configuration.html) carefully and also implemented that. But I got an error that not any idea for solving that.

I used this [section](https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/authentication.html) of the documentation for enabling authentication.

My received error:

> System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Unable to
> start Ocelot, errors are: Authentication Options
> AuthenticationProviderKey:BaseAuthenticationSchema,AllowedScopes:[] is
> unsupported authentication provider)'

Used packages:

**Ocelot(17.0.0)**

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer(5.0.11)**

Also sections of my codes for more specification:

***Program.cs***:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        config
                            .SetBasePath(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddJsonFile($"ocelot.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices(s =>
                    {
                        s.AddOcelot();
                    })
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                                  .UseSerilog((_, config) =>
                                  {
                                      config
                                          .MinimumLevel.Information()
                                          .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                                          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                                          .WriteTo.File(@"Logs\AllHttpRequestsLog.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day);
                                  })
                                  .Configure(app =>
                                  {
                                      app.UseMiddleware<HttpRequestsLoggingMiddleware>();
                                      app.UseOcelot().Wait();
                                  });
                    });
}
```

***Startup.cs***:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adding Authentication
    var baseAuthenticationProviderKey = "BaseAuthenticationSchema";

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })

    // Adding Jwt Bearer  
    .AddJwtBearer(baseAuthenticationProviderKey, options =>
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidAudience = "ValidAudience",
            ValidIssuer = "ValidIssuer ",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("IssuerSigningKey"))
        };
    });

    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddOcelot(_configuration);
}
```

And finally used configuration for the ocelot:

```
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/v1/banks",
  "DownstreamScheme": "https",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": 44371
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/market/banks",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ],
  "AuthenticationOptions": {
    "AuthenticationProviderKey": "BaseAuthenticationSchema",
    "AllowedScopes": []
  }
}
```

I investigated all articles and also the ocelot GitHub page like this open [issue](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/1094), But my problem was not solved. Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem using this [comment](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues/1094#issuecomment-713560869) on the Ocelot GitHub page open issues.

Just moved the authentication configuration from the `startup.cs` file to the `program.cs` file on the .`ConfigureServices` section.

Like this:

```
                    .ConfigureServices(s =>
                    {
                        // Adding Authentication
                        var baseAuthenticationProviderKey = "BaseAuthenticationSchema";

                        s.AddAuthentication(options =>
                        {
                            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        })

                        // Adding Jwt Bearer  
                        .AddJwtBearer(baseAuthenticationProviderKey, options =>
                        {
                            options.SaveToken = true;
                            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                            {
                                ValidateIssuer = true,
                                ValidateAudience = true,
                                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                ValidateLifetime = true,
                                ValidAudience = "ValidAudience",
                                ValidIssuer = "ValidIssuer",
                                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Secret"))
                            };
                        });
                        s.AddOcelot();
                    })
```

Also, removed that configuration from the `startup.cs` class.

Comment: Your real problem was messing Program.ca and Startup.cs. You are calling `s.AddOcelot();` in Program.cs and then `services.AddOcelot(_configuration);` in Startup.cs. It's not your fault, it's just outdated documentation that mixing configuration approaches from different epochs from dotnet core 1.1, 2.0 and 3.0. You should remove `.ConfigureServices(s =>` and `.Configure(app =>` blocks from Program.cs and move them into Startup.cs file: `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods.